# Rails NumericValueOutOfRange display field associated with error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 integer fields that create a sum on submit. On submit if there is a numeric field overflow for `avg_price` is it possible to display a message in the `if sales.errors.any?` error section with the error stating 'The field average price has a numeric field overflow' or something similar.

Currently I'm getting the following error:

```
PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR: numeric field overflow DETAIL: A field with precision 3, scale 1 must round to an absolute value less than 10^2
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "sales", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "price_1"
    t.integer "price_2"
    t.integer "price_3"
    t.decimal "avg_price", precision: 3, scale: 1
end
```

**Model**

```
def sale_sum
  if (self.price_1 && self.price_2 && self.price_3).present?
    self.avg_price = ((self.price_1 + self.price_2 + self.price_3)/3.0)
  end
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_with(model: sales, local: true) do |f| %>
  <% if sales.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(sales.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this sale from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% sales.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.number_field :price_1 %>
  <%= f.number_field :price_2 %>
  <%= f.number_field :price_3 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numericality](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) ValidationHelper of Rails.

```
validates :avg_price, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than: -100, less_than: 100}
```

It will show much more human readable error message.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I was able to create a custom message error which helped solved my issue. I shall post the results.

Answer (score 0):

With @mehedi answer, I stumbled across custom messages which helped me solve my issue. In my model I create a custom method that if the total of the fields was greater then 99.99 then display an error message.

```
def error_message
  if ((self.price_1 + self.price_2 + self.price_3)/3.0) > 99.99
    errors.add(:avg_price, "can't be more then 99.99")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use min or max property for number field. It is very helpfull for us.
For Example,

```
<%= f.number_field :price_1, min: 0, max: 2000 %>
```

Comment: You can also use model validation for less than and greater than value or less than  value.

Comment: You can also visit  https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates